# When to cache Tasks?

Tags: c#, caching, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I was watching [The zen of async: Best practices for best performance](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T) and [Stephen Toub](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/stephen%20toub%20-%20msft/) started to talk about Task caching, where instead of caching the results of task jobs you cache the tasks themselves. As far as i understood starting a new task for every job is expensive and it should be minimized as much as possible. At around 28:00 he showed this method:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> s_urlToContents;

public static async Task<string> GetContentsAsync(string url)
{
    string contents;
    if(!s_urlToContents.TryGetValue(url, out contents))
    {
        var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
        contents = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsString();
        s_urlToContents.TryAdd(url, contents);
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Which at a first look looks like a good thought out method where you cache results, i didn't event think about caching the job of getting the contents.

And than he showed this method:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> s_urlToContents;

public static Task<string> GetContentsAsync(string url)
{
    Task<string> contents;
    if(!s_urlToContents.TryGetValue(url, out contents))
    {
        contents = GetContentsAsync(url);
        contents.ContinueWith(t => s_urlToContents.TryAdd(url, t); },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
    return contents;
}

private static async Task<string> GetContentsAsync(string url)
{
    var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
    return response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

I have trouble understanding how this actually helps more than just storing the results.

Does this mean that you're using less Tasks to get the data?

And also, how do we know when to cache tasks? As far as i understand if you're caching in the wrong place you just get a load of overhead and stress the system too much

Comment: Yes, you're using less Task instances to get the data. As for the rest, it's the same as caching anything else, really. There's nothing special about Tasks in particular. Task != Thread.

Comment: The video is now here if someone's interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjLWWz2YnyQ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume you are talking to a remote service which takes the name of a city and returns its zip codes. The service is remote and under load so we are talking to a method with an asynchronous signature:

```
interface IZipCodeService
{
    Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> GetZipCodesAsync(string cityName);
}
```

Since the service needs a while for every request we would like to implement a local cache for it. Naturally the cache will also have an asynchronous signature maybe even implementing the same interface (see Facade pattern). A synchronous signature would break the best-practice of never calling asynchronous code synchronously with .Wait(), .Result or similar. At least the cache should leave that up to the caller.

So let's do a first iteration on this:

```
class ZipCodeCache : IZipCodeService
{
    private readonly IZipCodeService realService;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICollection<ZipCode>> zipCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICollection<ZipCode>>();

    public ZipCodeCache(IZipCodeService realService)
    {
        this.realService = realService;
    }

    public Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> GetZipCodesAsync(string cityName)
    {
        ICollection<ZipCode> zipCodes;
        if (zipCache.TryGetValue(cityName, out zipCodes))
        {
            // Already in cache. Returning cached value
            return Task.FromResult(zipCodes);
        }
        return this.realService.GetZipCodesAsync(cityName).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            this.zipCache.TryAdd(cityName, task.Result);
            return task.Result;
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the cache does not cache Task objects but the returned values of ZipCode collections. But by doing so it has to construct a Task for every cache hit by calling Task.FromResult and I think that is exactly what Stephen Toub tries to avoid. A Task object comes with overhead especially for the garbage collector because you are not only creating garbage but also every Task has a Finalizer which needs to be considered by the runtime.

The only option to work around this is by caching the whole Task object:

```
class ZipCodeCache2 : IZipCodeService
{
    private readonly IZipCodeService realService;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<ICollection<ZipCode>>> zipCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<ICollection<ZipCode>>>();

    public ZipCodeCache2(IZipCodeService realService)
    {
        this.realService = realService;
    }

    public Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> GetZipCodesAsync(string cityName)
    {
        Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> zipCodes;
        if (zipCache.TryGetValue(cityName, out zipCodes))
        {
            return zipCodes;
        }
        return this.realService.GetZipCodesAsync(cityName).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            this.zipCache.TryAdd(cityName, task);
            return task.Result;
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the creation of Tasks by calling Task.FromResult is gone. Furthermore it is not possible to avoid this Task creation when using the async/await keywords because internally they will create a Task to return no matter what your code has cached. Something like:

```
    public async Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> GetZipCodesAsync(string cityName)
    {
        Task<ICollection<ZipCode>> zipCodes;
        if (zipCache.TryGetValue(cityName, out zipCodes))
        {
            return zipCodes;
        }
```

will not compile.

Don't get confused by Stephen Toub's ContinueWith flags *TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion* and *TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously*. They are (only) another performance optimization which is not related to the main objective of caching Tasks.

As with every cache you should consider some mechanism which clean the cache from time to time and remove entries which are too old or invalid. You could also implement a policy which limits the cache to n entries and trys to cache the items requested most by introducing some counting.

I did some benchmarking with and without caching of Tasks. You can find the code here http://pastebin.com/SEr2838A and the results look like this on my machine (w/ .NET4.6)

```
Caching ZipCodes: 00:00:04.6653104
Gen0: 3560 Gen1: 0 Gen2: 0
Caching Tasks: 00:00:03.9452951
Gen0: 1017 Gen1: 0 Gen2: 0
```

Comment: In the OP's code, when caching tasks, it adds the task to the cache as soon as it *starts* the task.  In your code you add the task to the queue only when the task is *finished*.  That has an *enormous* difference in the semantics of the operation; and it is the primary reason that the OP's second snippet is often preferable to his first.  In your case, there's no meaningful difference between your two snippets.  The "cost" of creating a `Task` using `FromResult` is *minuscule*; when compared to the other long running operations, it's not relevant at all.

Comment: You completely missed the point. It is _precisely_ about avoiding allocating Task objects in Stephen Toub's video. Please first understand the question before judging on others. I'll add some benchmark to my answer to make Stephen Toub's statement a bit clearer.

Comment: Isn't it proxy pattern instead of facade?

Comment: @Divisadero it's more commonly known as the decorator pattern actually. The decorator can be thought as a more strict version of the wrapper/proxy, since it delegates logic to an object with the same interface that it implements itself, instead of delegating to some random object. It is naturally more composable that way. Yes, facade is a completely different pattern for combining/simplifying functionality by exposing a new interface.

Comment: For caching, one normally serializes the cached object so that subsequent changes to an object retrieved from cache don't affect the cached item.  I've tried serializing `Task<T>` with System.Text.Json's serializer, but can't deserialize it (as the Task doesn't have a parameterless constructor).  Any thoughts on this?  See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059550/system-json-net-deserializing-a-taskt-fails-no-parameterless-constructor) post.

Answer (score 10):

> I have trouble understanding how this actually helps more than just
>   storing the results.

When a method is marked with the `async` modifier, the compiler will automatically transform the underlying method into a state-machine, as Stephan demonstrates in previous slides. This means that the use of the first method will always trigger a creation of a `Task`.

In the second example, notice Stephan removed the `async` modifier and the signature of the method is now `public static Task<string> GetContentsAsync(string url)`. This now means that the responsibility of creating the `Task` is on the implementer of the method and not the compiler. By caching `Task<string>`, the only "penalty" of creating the `Task` (actually, two tasks, as `ContinueWith` will also create one) is when it's unavailable in the cache, and not foreach method call.

In this particular example, IMO, wasn't to re-use the network operation that is already ongoing when the first task executes, it was simply to reduce the amount of allocated `Task` objects.

> how do we know when to cache tasks?

Think of caching a `Task` as if it were anything else, and this question can be viewed from a more broad perspective: *When should I cache something?* The answer to this question is broad, but I think the most common use case is when you have an expensive operation which is on the hotpath of your application. Should you *always* be caching tasks? definitely not. The overhead of the state-machine allocation is usually neglectable. If needed, profile your app, and then (and only then) think if caching would be of use in your particular use case.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to cache tasks that are doing database calls? If lets say i have asynchronous get method that accepts an expression, and that method is used a lot of times with a specific expression, is it than a good idea to cache?

Comment: If the expressions ends up creating a delegate, then caching the delegate would be wise. Regarding the asynchronous get, that depends on how expensive that call is and how often you make it. If your application tells you it's a bottleneck, then it's a good candidate for caching.

Comment: The question is asking for a comparison of the differences between caching a `Task`, versus caching the results of the asynchronous operation.  This post doesn't answer that in any way.  The differences between a method that uses the `async` keyword versus an asynchronous method that doesn't use that keyword isn't what this question is about.  That the two implementations differ in that way isn't relevant to the semantic behavior they have, which is what is being asked about.

Comment: @Servy Not really. Although on the surface the question seems about: "Should I cache the result of asynchronous operation vs the `Task`", the example was referring to the comparison made by Stephan in his video, where it is crystal clear that his intention was to reduce `Task` allocation. There is of course benefit in caching the `Task` over caching the raw result, perhaps I should elaborate on that as well.

Comment: @Servy *That the two implementations differ in that way isn't relevant to the semantic behavior they have, which is what is being asked about.* I disagree with that statement as I think it actually misses the OPs question. But you're free to think so.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant difference is considering what happens when the method is called multiple times before the cache has been populated.

If you only cache the result, as is done in the first snippet, then if two (or three, or fifty) calls to the method are made before any of them has finished, they'll all start the actual operation to generate the results (in this case, performing a network request).  So you now have two, three, fifty, or whatever network requests that you're making, all of which are going to put their results in the cache when they finish.

When you cache the *task*, rather than the results of the operation, if a second, third, or fiftieth  call is made to this method after someone else starts their request, but before any of those requests have completed, they're all going to be given the same task representing that *one* network operation (or whatever long-running operation it is).  That means that you're only ever sending one network request, or only ever performing one expensive computation, rather than duplicating that work when you have multiple requests for the same result.

Also, consider the case where one request gets sent, and when it's 95% done, a second call is made to the method.  In the first snippet, since there is no result, it'll start from scratch and do 100% of the work.  The second snippet is going to result in that second invocation being handed a `Task` that's 95% done, so that second invocation is going to get its result much sooner than it would if using the first approach, in addition to the whole system just doing a *lot* less work.

In both cases, if you don't ever call the method when there is no cache, and another method has already started doing the work, then there is no meaningful difference between the two approaches.

You can create a fairly simple reproducible example to demonstrate this behavior.  Here we have a toy long running operation, and methods that either cache the result or cache the `Task` it returns.  When we fire off 5 of the operations all at once you'll see that the result caching performs the long running operation 5 times, and the task caching performs it just once.

```
public class AsynchronousCachingSample
{
    private static async Task<string> SomeLongRunningOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm starting a long running operation");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return "Result";
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> resultCache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    private static async Task<string> CacheResult(string key)
    {
        string output;
        if (!resultCache.TryGetValue(key, out output))
        {
            output = await SomeLongRunningOperation();
            resultCache.TryAdd(key, output);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> taskCache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>();
    private static Task<string> CacheTask(string key)
    {
        Task<string> output;
        if (!taskCache.TryGetValue(key, out output))
        {
            output = SomeLongRunningOperation();
            taskCache.TryAdd(key, output);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static async Task Test()
    {
        int repetitions = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Using result caching:");
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Repeat(false, repetitions)
              .Select(_ => CacheResult("Foo")));

        Console.WriteLine("Using task caching:");
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Repeat(false, repetitions)
              .Select(_ => CacheTask("Foo")));
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the specific implementation of the second approach you've provided has a few notable properties.  It's possible for the method to be called twice in such a way that both of them will *start* the long running operation before either task can finish *starting* the operation, and therefore cache the `Task` that represents that operation.  So while it'd be *much* harder than with the first snippet, it *is* possible for whatever the long running operation is to be run twice.  There would need to be more robust locking around checking the cache, starting a new operation, and then populating the cache, in order to prevent that.  If doing whatever the long running task is multiple times on rare occasions would just be wasting a bit of time, then the current code is probably fine, but if it's important that the operation *never* be performed multiple times (say, because it cases side effects) then the current code isn't complete.

Comment: *The second snippet is going to result in that second invocation being handed a Task that's 95% done*. How is that so? The caching of the `Task` happens only on completion of the original `Task` via it's continuation only once it ran to completion, not directly after the `Task` has started.

Comment: Also, what you're offering is dangerous. Assume the task was faulted, what then? You're caching a `Task` which has yet completed and may fail, and you're serving that same task over and over again.

Comment: @Servy, frankly it is bad manners to write answers and vote others without even having watched the video OP is refering to. Your implementation completely missed the point which is _not_ "how to implement a certain cache policy" but "why and when to reuse Task objects" _plus_ it has serious flaw: It caches failed Tasks as well - and should not be publicly shown on SO. Please be so kind remove your votes and answer until you fully understood the problem. I'll add some benchmark to my answer to elaborate more on Stephen Toub's point.

Comment: @ThomasZeman To be fair, whether or not caching a faulted task is dangerous is application dependent. Either way, you will need some logic to clear "expired" cache entries, so caching a faulted task for some period of time before retrying is a perfectly valid approach for many situations and a pattern that I have used before.

Comment: There is also the option of immediately removing faulted tasks so that attempts to retry will actually retry instead of sending the same faulted task back but you still only get 1 real request at a time for concurrent requests. Multiple concurrent requests for the same faulty resource will just all get the same faulted task back until they retry.