# How to serialize Task<TResult> with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, task

Consider

```
public class InQuestion<TType>
{
    // JsonConverter(typeof CustomConverter))
    public Task<TType> toConvert { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I (de)serialize this class with json.net?**

What I think I actually want to serialize is the underlying Task< T >.Result, which can then be deserialized with Task< T >.FromResult(). If I am to use custom JsonConverter, I cannot pass generic TType through Attribute, to reconstruct (or retrieve) TType object in the JsonConverter. Hence I'm stuck.

Question came to be from this code:

```
public class Program
{
    public class InQuestion<TType>
    {
        public Task<TType> toConvert { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var questionable = new InQuestion<Result>();
        questionable.toConvert = Task.Run(async () => new Result { value = 42 });
        await questionable.toConvert; 

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questionable);
        Debug.WriteLine(json); 
        InQuestion<Result> back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(InQuestion<Result>)) as InQuestion<Result>;
        Debug.Assert(back?.toConvert?.Result?.value == 42); 
    }
}
```

which, surprisingly to me, **halts**, during the call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1886 talks about the issue and recommends reasonable "Don't ever serialize/deserialize task.", but doesn't actually advice how to serialize the underlying Task< T >.Result.

Comment: holup... why are we doing this in the first place `Task<TType> toConvert` Why do you need ta task here?

Comment: The approach itself is questionable, even if it works with the provided answer. You can [read more about how to work with non-blocking code with Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)

Comment: @TheGeneral Consider caching collection of Task<T>, in a Generic dictionary for arbitrary type Type, as per: stackoverflow.com/questions/36084495/when-to-cache-tasks (the code in question is from presentation by Stephen Toub).I want to provide a class that will sometimes provide callers with a future, but usually with a Task<T> that has already been completed, in both ways exposing it as a Task<T>. If caller awaits Task.Result, for cached tasks, it will return immedietelly. I then need to (de)serialize this cache, essentially ConcurrentDictionary<K,Task<T>>, but only saving T, not Tasks itself

Answer (score 1):

A `Task` is a promise of a future value, and of course you cannot serialize a value that has yet to be provided.

Because the `InQuestion` object holds a `Task` member, you cannot serialize and deserialize the `InQuestion` object.

The workaround is to serialize the result, and reconstruct the `InQuestion` object after deserialization.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var questionable = new InQuestion<Result>();
    questionable.toConvert = Task.Run(async () => new Result { value = 42 });

    Result result = await questionable.toConvert;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    
    Result back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof<Result>) as Result;

    InQuestion<Result> reconstructed = new InQuestion<Result>()
    {
        toConvert = Task.FromResult(back)
    };
}
```

Comment: This does not help my use case at all. Consider caching collection of Task<T>, in a Generic dictionary for arbitrary type Type, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084495/when-to-cache-tasks (the code in question is from presentation by Stephen Toub). I want to provide a class that will sometimes provide callers with a future, but usually with a Task<T> that has already been completed, in both ways exposing it as a Task<T>. If caller awaits Task.Result, for cached tasks, it will return immedietelly. I then need to (de)serialize this cache, essentially ConcurrentDictionary<K,Task<T>>

Comment: And I don't know how to instruct json.net to (un)wrap TResult object from Task<TResult> during (de)serialization, since TResult can be any generic type, and JsonConverter interface just passes me an 'object'. The code in Main is a calling code, I'd like to implement that functionality in class InQuestion<T>, so that it serializes just the TResult (and omits from serialization uncompleted Tasks, which would be very rare)

Comment: There is no way to serialize a task. If your use case requires you to do impossible things, I would take a step back and find out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions to this problem.

From the [Add support for generic JsonConverter instantiation](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1332):

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InQuestionConverter<>))]
    public class InQuestion<TResult>
    {
        public Task<TResult> toConvert { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Result result &&
                   value == result.value &&
                   text == result.text;
        }
    }

    public class InQuestionConverter<TResult> : JsonConverter<InQuestion<TResult>>
    {
        public override InQuestion<TResult> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, InQuestion<TResult> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (hasExistingValue)
                existingValue.toConvert = Task.FromResult(serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(reader));
            else
                existingValue = new InQuestion<TResult>
                {
                    toConvert = Task.FromResult(serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(reader))
                };
            return existingValue;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, InQuestion<TResult> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.toConvert.Result, typeof(TResult));
        }
    }

    public sealed class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
        {
            var typeInfo = objectType.GetTypeInfo();
            if (typeInfo.IsGenericType && !typeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                var jsonConverterAttribute = typeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonConverterAttribute>();
                if (jsonConverterAttribute != null && jsonConverterAttribute.ConverterType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                {
                    Type t = jsonConverterAttribute.ConverterType.MakeGenericType(typeInfo.GenericTypeArguments);
                    object[] parameters = jsonConverterAttribute.ConverterParameters;
                    return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(t, parameters);
                }
            }
            return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var questionable = new InQuestion<Result>();
        questionable.toConvert = Task.Run(async () => { return new Result { value = 42, text = "fox" };  });
        questionable.toConvert.Wait();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questionable, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() });
        InQuestion<Result> back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(InQuestion<Result>), new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() }) as InQuestion<Result>;

        Debug.Assert(back.toConvert.Result.Equals(questionable.toConvert.Result));
        return;
    }
```

Enables a custom `ContractResolver` which will point to correct generic instantiation of `JsonConverter<TResult>`, in which serialization is straightforward. This requires configuring `JsonSerializerSettings` and providing serialization for the entire `InQuestion` class (note that converter doesn't check for Task.IsCompleted in this sample).

Alternatively, using JsonConverterAttribute just on properties of type `Task<T>` and relying on reflection to retrieve TResult type from non-generic Converter:

```
    public class InQuestion<TResult>
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(FromTaskOfTConverter))]
        public Task<TResult> toConvert { get; set; }
    }

    public class FromTaskOfTConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return IsDerivedFromTaskOfT(objectType);
        }

        static bool IsDerivedFromTaskOfT(Type type)
        {
            while (type.BaseType != typeof(object))
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
                    return true;
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Debug.Assert(IsDerivedFromTaskOfT(objectType));
            Type TResult = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            object ResultValue = serializer.Deserialize(reader, TResult);
            return typeof(Task).GetMethod("FromResult").MakeGenericMethod(TResult).Invoke(null, new[] { ResultValue });
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Type objectType = value.GetType();
            Debug.Assert(IsDerivedFromTaskOfT(objectType));

            Type TResult = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type TaskOfTResult = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(TResult);

            if ((bool)TaskOfTResult.GetProperty("IsCompleted").GetValue(value) == true)
            {
                object ResultValue = TaskOfTResult.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(value);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, ResultValue, TResult);
            }
            else
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, Activator.CreateInstance(TResult));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var questionable = new InQuestion<Result>();
        questionable.toConvert = Task.Run(async () => { return new Result { value = 42, text = "fox" }; });
        questionable.toConvert.Wait();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questionable);
        InQuestion<Result> back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(InQuestion<Result>)) as InQuestion<Result>;

        Debug.Assert(back.toConvert.Result.Equals(questionable.toConvert.Result));
        return;
    }
```

With all that, I won't mark this accepted, since I lack understanding in both generics reflection and json.net.

Comment: Looking at this solution, it appears if the Task is not completed, you serialize a default instance of T instead. There will be no distinction between there being a default instance because it's uninitialized or there being a default instance because that's the actual correct value.