# System.Json.Net - deserializing a Task<T> fails (no parameterless constructor)

Tags: caching, async-await, jsonserializer, system.text.json

I'm running into a problem where I can't deserialize a string into a Task using `System.Text.Json` (.Net 5).

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Task<TItem>>(serializedItem)
```

#### Background

I have a localized cache and store in it items retrieved from the DB.

I can't store the actual item in the cache, because any subsequent manipulation of the object results in the cached item being manipulation, affecting all further uses.  I therefore store a serialized copy of the object.

Regarding performance...

I'm using the async/await pattern to call the DB (the whole app is async).

I read an article (may have been a video) in which Stephen Toub described the performance advantage of caching the Task.  This SO article [When to cache Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084495/when-to-cache-tasks) goes into the details.  Anyhow, I thought I'd try to take advantage of this (it works perfectly without serialization) using the following in my local cache "layer":

1. If Task is in my cache, await it and return the result.
2. Otherwise, call the DB method without awaiting it and add the resultant task to the cache

When I add serialization, then the deserialization of the task:

```
Task<TItem>? cachedItem = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Task<TItem>>(serializedItem);
```

results in

> Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a
> singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor
> annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported.

Comment: How is this related to `async-await`? Does it work if it's synchronous?

Comment: You can't serialize or deserialize a `Task<T>`, it is an operation that returns its result asynchronously, not a data object from which a meaningful contract can be derived.  It wraps an `Action<T>` or other delegate, and you can't serialize a delegate.  See: [how come BinaryFormatter can serialize an Action<> but Json.net cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139733/3744182).  Of course that answer is for [tag:json.net], but [tag:system.text.json] is even more limited and doesn't even attempt to support `[Serializable]` serialization, as it doesn't serialize members, only properties.

Comment: And while `Action<T>` is technically marked as `[Serializable]`, `Task<T>` [is not](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Future.cs,5ca7b77f3df89fc6), so there's no reason to think it could be serialized.

Comment: Is that sufficient  for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is relatively straightforward - serialize the data inside the Task result, not the task itself.

If you aren't using something like memcached but rather using something like a simple `Dictionary` in-process object cache then serializing and deserializing seems like a rather heavy approach to cloning objects though.